# grep: memory exhausted - Error running on Large Data Set

Tags: linux, memory, grep, sed

I am trying to clean an email list with huge data.

When I try this:

```
pv "Email-Raw.txt" | grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/$/' Segment00.txt) > RESULT-1.txt
```

I get `grep: memory exhausted`

How do I solve this? Please help.

Comment: What's the output of `wc Segment00.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

As, in this case, I wanted to match the EXACT MATCH of the whole line, I solved it by modifying the command to - `pv "Email-Raw.txt" | grep -vxFf Segment00.txt) > RESULT-1.txt`

Note: this may not work if you partially want to match text in each line.